# How do you dynamically get a file's path in Google Colab with Python?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to dynamically get a Python file's path location inside of Google Colab but I cannot find out how. I am trying to get a similar output of`dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))`
on a Windows machine.

I have tried `os.getcwd`, but this only outputs the String of `"builtIn_function_or_method"`. Is it possible to get a file's directory in Google Colab?

Comment: The Windows solution should work in any environment that has a filesystem.  What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Also it looks like you forgot the parentheses on the end of `getcwd`. It;s a _function_, so you need parentheses to _call_ it.   `os.getcwd()`

Comment: @JohnGordon Appreciate the spot on `os.getcwd()` I didn't notice the missing parentheses. As far as the Windows method, I keep getting `name '__file__' is not defined`

Comment: `__file__` is typically not defined in interactive shells.  I've never used Google Collab -- is it an interactive shell?

Comment: @JohnGordon It’s basically a Google-hosted instance of Jupyter, which is a spin off of IPython, which is itself an interactive shell. Safe to say Colab is one as well.

Comment: as I remeber `Google Colab` uses `Google Drive` to keep `data` and `notebooks` and it may need to run `from google.colab import drive` `drive.mount('/content/drive')` to have access. More: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=RWSJpsyKqHjH